# how to obtain a function's name and/or a description given a pointer

Tags: python

I am using **Python 2.7**. Is there a way to associate a name, description and perhaps other metadata with a function so that I don't have to use an external dictionary to keep such information like in the code below:

```
def predicateA(v):
    # some logic that eventually returns a True/False value
    return True

def predicateB(v):
    # some logic that eventually returns a True/False value
    return False

predicateNames={}
predicateNames[predicateA]='name and description for predicateA'
predicateNames[predicateB]='name and description for predicateB'

predicates = [predicateA, predicateB]

def evalForAllPredicates(v):
    for f in predicates:
       result = f(v)
       print "function %s returned: %s" % (predicateNames[f], result)

evalForAllPredicates(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a function's name and its docstring through the `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes. A function's docstring is just a string literal placed as the first statement in the function. Convention is to use triple-quotes to enclose docstrings as they are expected to span many lines.

```
def predicateA(v):
    """
    some logic that eventually returns a True/False value
    """
    return True

print "Name:", predicateA.__name__
print "Doc:", predicateB.__doc__
```

To associate arbitrary metadata to a function, just assign any attribute you like to the function as if it were an ordinary object, which it is after all.

```
def predicateB(v):
    """
    some logic that eventually returns a True/False value
    """
    return False

predicateA.alwaysReturnsFalse = False
predicateB.alwaysReturnsFalse = True

for pred in [predicateA, predicateB]:
    print "Function:", pred.__name__
    print "Documentation:", pred.__doc__
    if pred.alwaysReturnsFalse:
        print "(This function always returns false)"
```

```
Function: predicateA
Documentation:
    some logic that eventually returns a True/False value

Function: predicateB
Documentation:
    some logic that eventually returns a True/False value

(This function always returns false)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your function has appropriate [doc string](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings), you can use the `__name__` and `__doc__` attribute

```
>>> def predicateA(v):
    '''some logic that eventually returns a True/False value
    '''
    return True

>>> predicateA.__doc__
'some logic that eventually returns a True/False value\n    '
>>> predicateA.__name__
'predicateA'
```

In your example, the description that you want is through doc string and is placed within triple double or single code just after the function header. Unless you do so, your `__doc__` would return empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all sorts of attributes to the function, and you can incoude a doc string:

```
def fun(x)
    """
    Description ...
    """
    pass

fun.foo = 2
fun.baz = "will do naught"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes to get the function name and doc-string respectively.